# How to simulate waiting for a message in bot framework composer

Tags: botframework, bot-framework-composer

I am new to using this tool Bot Framework Composer , I am trying to make the message from the bot simulate that it is late and show the 3 ellipsis points, I am doing it with activity, but it only works if the message really takes time, but I want it to delay as if using task.delay, any suggestion?

[Activity

```
    type = Typing
```

]

Comment: any updates? Facing the same problem

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to use the `Send an HTTP request` action. You would need to make sure whatever http endpoint you were calling with this action would take long enough for you to fit your scenario. (You could build your own that would do exactly that)